# Yarn Type Error: "Invalid Number of Spaces"

Tags: npm, typeerror, yarnpkg

I have a work project that is configured using yarn. I've used npm commands on other projects for the company, but for this project, I need to use yarn. The reason that I haven't used yarn before is because whenever I run any yarn commands locally, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid number of spaces
    at tokenise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:63358:17)
    at tokenise.next (<anonymous>)
```

I'm on a mac and have tried running `yarn`, `brew install yarn`,`npm install --global yarn` and `curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash`. I've also tried `npm uninstall yarn`and `brew uninstall yarn` to try to start fresh, but after each attempt at removing and reinstalling, I get the same error.

The cloned repository that I'm working with includes a `.yarnrc` file and a `yarn.lock` file. Also, I'm on a work vpn, and have to install dependencies over  the vpn, so I have a mirror registry in my `.yarnrc` file.

Any suggestions on where to start troubleshooting? Obviously, I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete your yarn.lock file and then try your yarn commands. This should be deleted whenever you want to reinstall the application or node modules.
For your information, yarn. lock is a flattened list of all dependencies that your projects needs to run, transitive dependencies are defined at the same level as dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because the project had a .nprmc file. Inside of it was a Nexus registry, but it had been commented out this way:

```
#registry=http://nexus.projects.com:8081/repository/npm-group/
```

The solution was to **add a space between # and registry.**

Note: If you have a yarnc file, check that too.